# How to make achieve better positioning of elements in a tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I believe that there are quicker and/or better ways of drawing images similar to the one in the MWE below.

[image]

As you can see my way is quite cumbersome. For example, I would like to learn a way to make the arrows "start" above (vertical arrow) and exactly to the east (red arrow) of the epsilon-sign. I usually test starting positions for the arrows until it looks ok. For this simple figure it is ok but in the future this way will be too time consuming.

Things I've tried are using `nodes` and `children` thinking I could change the positions of the children. I also tried using `draw` but I could not get either to look even halfway decent.

Does anyone know a better way of doing this than what I've shown below? Preferably using `tikzpicture` since that is what I'm most accustomed to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[left] at (0,0) {Endogenous variable};
\node[left] at (-2,-1.5) {$\epsilon_i$};
\node[right] at (1,0) {Dependent Variable};

\draw[->] (0,0) to (1,0); %Independent to Dependent Variable

\draw[->, color=red] (-1.8,-1.3) to (1,-0.5); %Epsilon to Dependent Variable

\draw[->] (-2.3,-1.3) to (-2.3,-0.25); %epsilon to Independent Variable

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've updated the post with an image of what you want drawn, and removed the `axis` environment (it's not necessary in your approach, but also doesn't compile as-is in your code). Consider voting as part of your contribution to this site.

Comment: Thank you! I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet. But I'll try to remember to do it as soon as I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Let me give you several different approaches, since I don't know how your different diagrams eventually should look like.

First of all, you don't need the `axis` environment. This is only needed if you want to plot a diagram using PGFplots which you don't do here.

Second, it is a good idea to name nodes, because once nodes have a name, it is very easy to position other nodes relative to them or draw arrows or lines between the nodes. A node can be given a name by adding its name in parentheses. For, example, the following node is named `e`:

```
\node at (0,-1.5) (e) {$\epsilon_i$};
```

So, a first simple approach could look like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0,0) (endo) {Endogenous variable};
\node at (0,-1.5) (e) {$\epsilon_i$};
\node at (4,0) (dept) {Dependent variable};

\draw[->] (endo) to (dept); % Independent to Dependent Variable

\draw[->, red] (e) to (dept); % Epsilon to Dependent Variable

\draw[->] (e) to (endo); % Epsilon to Independent Variable

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Now, you already load the `positioning` library in your example above, probably without knowing its benefits. You actually can use this library to easily position nodes relative to each other. So, you don't need to define any coordinates in an absolute way (except maybe for the first node), which may come handy in certain cases:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0,0) (endo) {Endogenous variable};
\node[below=1cm of endo] (e) {$\epsilon_i$};
\node[right=1cm of endo] (dept) {Dependent variable};

\draw[->] (endo) to (dept); % Independent to Dependent Variable

\draw[->, red] (e) to (dept); % Epsilon to Dependent Variable

\draw[->] (e) to (endo); % Epsilon to Independent Variable

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Finally, I would like to introduce to you a way to draw matrix-like diagrams also known as commutative diagrams. I am not sure whether this is what you are after, but the above diagram can certainly also be created using this approach. The logic is similar to the coding of arrays. In an `tikzcd` environment, all nodes are already meant to be in math mode, so you need to tell LaTeX that the two text elements are not math:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
\textrm{Endogenous variable} \arrow[r] & \textrm{Dependent variable} \\
\epsilon_i \arrow[u] \arrow[ur, red] & 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Of course, there are even more ways to achieve the above output. It depends on the logic of the diagrams you want to create.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer! I believe middle example - using `positioning` is exactly what I was looking for!