# How to \draw negated arrows between nodes in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

[image]

Building on a previous question of mine [about `tikzpicture`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665556/how-to-make-achieve-better-positioning-of-elements-in-a-tikzpicture), how do I get the encircled arrows in the image as arrows between nodes, and what is the name of the symbol? I assume I still use `draw` but I have not been able to figure it out.
Also a list of arrow-options for `draw` would be appreciated.

Currently I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) (qob) {Quarter of Birth};
\node[right=1cm of qob] (sch) {Schooling};
\node[right=1cm of sch] (wage) {Wage};
\node[below=1cm of sch] (abi) {Ability $\in \:u$};

\draw[$\nsenwarrows$] (abi) to (sch);
\draw[->, red] (abi) to (sch);
\draw[->] (abi) to (wage);
\draw[->] (qob) to (sch); %here I want to have "relevance" above the arrow
\draw[->] (sch) to (wage); %here i want a "?" above the arrow
\draw[\n$\nsenwarrows$] %here I want to replace the arrow with \nsenwarrows and write "exogeneity" below

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the libraries `decorations.pathreplacing` and `calc` to your preamble, along with the following `tikzset`:

```
\tikzset{nsenwarrows/.style={decorate, decoration={show path construction,
    lineto code={
        \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst); \pgfgetlastxy{\xstart}{\ystart};
        \path (\tikzinputsegmentlast); \pgfgetlastxy{\xend}{\yend};
        \path ($(0,0)!1.5pt!(\ystart-\yend,\xend-\xstart)$); \pgfgetlastxy{\xperp}{\yperp}; 
        \draw[->, shift={($(-\xperp,-\yperp)$)}, shorten <=1.5pt, shorten >=1.5pt, #1] (\xstart,\ystart)--(\xend,\yend);
        \draw[->, shift={(\xperp,\yperp)}, shorten <=1.5pt, shorten >=1.5pt, #1] (\xend,\yend)--(\xstart,\ystart);
        \draw[#1] ($.5*(\xstart,\ystart)+.5*(\xend,\yend)+4*(\xperp,\yperp)$)--($.5*(\xstart,\ystart)+.5*(\xend,\yend)-4*(\xperp,\yperp)$);
    }}}, nsenwarrows/.default={}
}
```

Then you can use the key `nsenwarrows` in `\draw` statements to produce the negated arrows between nodes. For example:

```
\draw[nsenwarrows] (abi) to node[below left]{exogeneity} (qob);
\draw[nsenwarrows=red] (abi) to (sch);
```

[image]

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calc}

\tikzset{nsenwarrows/.style={decorate, decoration={show path construction,
    lineto code={
        \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst); \pgfgetlastxy{\xstart}{\ystart};
        \path (\tikzinputsegmentlast); \pgfgetlastxy{\xend}{\yend};
        \path ($(0,0)!1.5pt!(\ystart-\yend,\xend-\xstart)$); \pgfgetlastxy{\xperp}{\yperp}; 
        \draw[->, shift={($(-\xperp,-\yperp)$)}, shorten <=1.5pt, shorten >=1.5pt, #1] (\xstart,\ystart)--(\xend,\yend);
        \draw[->, shift={(\xperp,\yperp)}, shorten <=1.5pt, shorten >=1.5pt, #1] (\xend,\yend)--(\xstart,\ystart);
        \draw[#1] ($.5*(\xstart,\ystart)+.5*(\xend,\yend)+4*(\xperp,\yperp)$)--($.5*(\xstart,\ystart)+.5*(\xend,\yend)-4*(\xperp,\yperp)$);
    }}}, nsenwarrows/.default={}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) (qob) {Quarter of Birth};
\node[right=1cm of qob] (sch) {Schooling};
\node[right=1cm of sch] (wage) {Wage};
\node[below=1cm of sch] (abi) {Ability $\in \:u$};

\draw[nsenwarrows=red] (abi) to (sch);
\draw[->] (abi) to (wage);
\draw[->] (qob) to (sch); %here I want to have "relevance" above the arrow
\draw[->] (sch) to (wage); %here i want a "?" above the arrow
\draw[nsenwarrows] (abi) to node[below left]{exogeneity} (qob); %here I want to replace the arrow with \nsenwarrows and write "exogeneity" below

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

As an alternative, this is easier with `tikz-cd`. Define a macro `\nsenwarrows` that takes one required argument (direction) and one optional argument (label). For example,

`\nsenwarrows[\textup{\scriptsize exogeneity}]{ul}`

will draw the arrow from the current cell up-left with the given label.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\nsenwarrows}[2][]{\arrow[#2, shift left=2pt, shorten=2mm, "|"marking, "#1", outer sep=1mm]\arrow[#2, shift right=2pt, <-, shorten=2mm, "|"marking]}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5cm, row sep=1cm]
\textup{Quarter of Birth}\arrow[r, "\textup{\scriptsize relevance}"] & \textup{Schooling}\arrow[r, "?"] & \textup{Wage}\\
 & \textup{Ability}\in u\arrow[ur]\arrow[u, red]\nsenwarrows[\textup{\scriptsize exogeneity}]{ul}
\end{tikzcd} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
However for my use case this is a "worst case"-solution.
A feature of `tikzpicture` that I value is that when using `node` and `draw` it is very clear which part of the code does what. That makes it easier to use in when collaborating with others, which I do on this project (should have clarified that earlier).

Comment: @AoMRos: I added a solution that is more portable, without `tikz-cd`. Does that do what you want?

Comment: I believe that will be perfect! Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 4):

The name of the symbol is `\nsenwarrows` and it can be found in `fdsymbol` and `MnSymbol` packages. To have the symbol between nodes just load a package that include the symbol and insert it as a node between those you want to have it between them. You can get some initial ideas from the code below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,fdsymbol,xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) {Quarter of Birth};
        \draw[very thick,->] (2,0) -- (4,0) node[above,midway] {\footnotesize relevance};
        \node at (5,0) {Schooling};
        \draw[very thick,->] (6,0) -- (8,0) node[above,midway] {?};
        \node at (9,0) {Wage};
        \node at (3,-0.5) {\Large $\nsenwarrows$};\node at (3,-1) {\footnotesize exogeneity};
        \node at (7,-0.5) {\color{red}\large $\uparrow$}; \node at (7,-1) {Ability $\in u$};
        \draw[very thick,->] (8.1,-0.9) -- (9,-0.3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Not exactly what I'm looking for though. I want to be able to simply draw the arrows using `to` rather than having to write coordinates. This is because using coordinates will quickly become way to cumbersome in the later stages of my project. 
I need the signs and words above/below the arrows to "follow" them. Preferably by everything in the same `\draw`-command.

Comment: @AoMRos You can just use the node with that symbol a path between nodes that's not drawn as the other nodes that are placed midway and sloped.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand how you mean. Bear in mind that I'm a LaTex-novice. Thank you for your reply though. :)